# How to formulate this query in Postgres without using views

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this exercise query that I'm trying to formulate, which also happens to be quite tricky because the exercise explicitly tells you not to use views. It's based on the Musicbrainz database schema, but the only relations that are used, stripped of all the unused attributes, are:

```
label {id(PK), name}

release {id(PK), name}

-- associates a label to all its releases
release_label {id(PK), release(FK), label(FK)}
```

The query is: "list all the pairs of records labels that never released any common release BUT published a release in collaboration with the same third record label (show the names of the pairs of record labels)".

I've been trying to wrap my head around this query for days, but I only solved the first half (pairs of labels that never released anything in common) using some self joins on the same table to create the pairs

```
SELECT DISTINCT label_1.name, label_2.name
FROM label label_1 JOIN label label_2 ON label_1.name < label_2.name
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM release release_A 
      JOIN release_label RLA ON release_A.id = RLA.release
      JOIN label label_A ON RLA.label = label_A.id
      JOIN release release_B ON release_A.name = release_B.name
      JOIN release_label RLB ON release_B.id = RLB.release
      JOIN label label_B ON RLB.label = label_B.id
      WHERE label_1.name = label_A.name AND label_2.name = label_B.name
     )
```

Basically the outer query creates every pair of record labels in order and each pair gets selected using a correlated subquery that search if there isn't any common release between those two record labels. This part works as intended, but I have no idea how to find the same third label without using any views or any conditional or control structures. Help.

Comment: Are common table expressions allowed? With those you could simulate views.

Comment: No, you can't use those either

Comment: Then how about a SQL function?

Comment: Not even those unfortunately, there are a lot of restrictions just for difficulty's sake

Comment: oops no CTE, did not see this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a third self join of *label* with two added `EXISTS` clauses differing in their `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT label_1.name, label_2.name, label_3.name
FROM label label_1
JOIN label label_2 ON label_1.name < label_2.name
JOIN label label_3 ON label_3.name <> label_1.name
                   AND label_3.name <> label_2.name
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1
      FROM release release_A 
      JOIN release_label RLA ON release_A.id = RLA.release
      JOIN label label_A ON RLA.label = label_A.id
      JOIN release release_B ON release_A.name = release_B.name
      JOIN release_label RLB ON release_B.id = RLB.release
      JOIN label label_B ON RLB.label = label_B.id
      WHERE label_1.name = label_A.name
        AND label_2.name = label_B.name
     )
 AND EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
      FROM release release_A 
      JOIN release_label RLA ON release_A.id = RLA.release
      JOIN label label_A ON RLA.label = label_A.id
      JOIN release release_B ON release_A.name = release_B.name
      JOIN release_label RLB ON release_B.id = RLB.release
      JOIN label label_B ON RLB.label = label_B.id
      WHERE label_1.name = label_A.name 
        AND label_3.name = label_B.name
     )
 AND EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
      FROM release release_A 
      JOIN release_label RLA ON release_A.id = RLA.release
      JOIN label label_A ON RLA.label = label_A.id
      JOIN release release_B ON release_A.name = release_B.name
      JOIN release_label RLB ON release_B.id = RLB.release
      JOIN label label_B ON RLB.label = label_B.id
      WHERE label_2.name = label_A.name 
        AND label_3.name = label_B.name
     )
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of this before. It's extremely slow though and it takes like 4 minutes to run on my database, but it doesn't matter. I mean, the exercise was about not using CTEs, but I just tried adding a CTE and the runtime went from 4 minutes to 90 ms

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help. Yes, CTEs prevent from re-running the same resultset multiple times which we repeat here with different `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Query

```sql
with
q_00 as (
-- This should already be unique in release_label,
-- but the unique key is not specified in the schema
select distinct release, label
from release_label
),
q_01 as (
-- Releases and pairs of labels common to that release
-- includes pairs (l1, l2) = (l2, l1)
select a.release  as r1
     , a.label    as l1
     , b.label    as l2
from q_00 as a
join q_00 as b on a.release = b.release
              and a.label  != b.label
),
q_02 as (
-- All pairs of labels which do have a common release
-- includes pairs (l1, l2) = (l2, l1)
select distinct l1, l2
from q_01
),
q_03 as (
-- All possible pairs of labels
-- includes pairs (l1, l2) = (l2, l1)
select distinct
       a.label    as l1
     , b.label    as l2
from q_00 as a
join q_00 as b on a.label != b.label
),
q_04 as (
-- All pairs of labels which do NOT have a common release
-- includes pairs (l1, l2) = (l2, l1)
select l1, l2 from q_03
except
select l1, l2 from q_02
),
q_05 as (
-- l1 and l2 did not work together, but they
-- both worked with l3
select
       a.l1 as l1
     , a.l2 as l2
     , b.l2 as l3
from q_04 as a
join q_02 as b on b.l1 = a.l1
join q_02 as c on c.l1 = a.l2 and c.l2 = b.l2
)
-- Result with label names, no repeats (l1, l2) = (l2, l1)
-- lbl_1 and lbl_2 did not work together, but they
-- both worked with lbl_3
select distinct
       b.name as lbl_1
     , c.name as lbl_2
     , d.name as lbl_3
from q_05  as a
join label as b on b.id = a.l1
join label as c on c.id = a.l2
join label as d on d.id = a.l3
where b.name < c.name
order by lbl_1, lbl_2, lbl_3
;
```

### Testing

#### Create tables

```sql
create table label (
    id    int  not null
  , name  text not null

  , constraint pk_label primary key (id)
  );

create table release (
    id    int  not null
  , name  text not null

  , constraint pk_release primary key (id)
);

create table release_label (
    id       int  not null
  , release  int  not null
  , label    int  not null

  , constraint pk_rel_lbl primary key (id)

  , constraint fk1_rel_lbl foreign key (release)
                             references release (id)

  , constraint fk2_rel_lbl foreign key (label)
                             references label (id)
);
```

#### Add sample data

```sql
insert into label (id, name)
values
(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'),
(5, 'E'), (6, 'F'), (7, 'G'), (8, 'H');

insert into release (id, "name")
values
( 1, 'R01'), ( 2, 'R02'), ( 3, 'R03'), ( 4, 'R04'),
( 5, 'R05'), ( 6, 'R06'), ( 7, 'R07'), ( 8, 'R08');

insert into release_label (id, release, label)
values
-- R01 (A, F, H)
  (11, 1, 1)
, (12, 1, 6)
, (13, 1, 8)

-- R02 (B)
, (21, 2, 2)

-- R03 (C, D)
, (31, 3, 3)
, (32, 3, 4)

-- R04 (B, F)
, (41, 4, 2)
, (42, 4, 6)

-- R05 (A, F)
, (51, 5, 1)
, (52, 5, 6)

-- R06 (D, G)
, (61, 6, 4)
, (62, 6, 7)

-- R07 (A, G)
, (71, 7, 1)
, (72, 7, 7)

-- R08 (E)
, (81, 8, 5)
;
```

#### Result

```
 lbl_1 | lbl_2 | lbl_3
-------+-------+-------
 A     | B     | F
 A     | D     | G
 B     | H     | F
 C     | G     | D
 F     | G     | A
 G     | H     | A
(6 rows)
```